# Python sort JSON by array value

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON like this

```
[{'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
                 'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
                 'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000},
 {'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
                 'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
                 'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000}]
```

How can I sort by `percentage` and it's percentage value(2nd object in a list in each of the dictionaries (`neutral`, `positive`, `negative`)

I tried this :

```
sorted(dict[key], key=lambda function)
```

but this looks like it's not applicable and I'm a bit stuck. How to do this?

Comment: @DirtyBit oh good comment, i'll update a question !

Comment: @RnD Cheers, will do so further on !

Comment: That is not sorting but replacing the values of the second element in the dict.

Comment: you are continuosly changin the output desired by editing your question. stick with one if you want people to help.

Comment: @MilesDavisi only eddited it once tho, idk why is it has gone through multiple edits by users(and accepted only 1 change w/ a prettyfied JSON )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question as it has undergone lots of edits. I think this is what you are searching for...

```
>>>p
[{'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
   'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
   'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000},
 {'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
   'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
   'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000}]
>>>for i in p:
    i["percentage"]=sorted(i["percentage"].items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
>>>p
[{'percentage': [('neutral', [388133213, 90.18]),
   ('positive', [39129393, 9.09]),
   ('negative', [3132394, 0.73])],
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000},
 {'percentage': [('neutral', [388133213, 90.18]),
   ('positive', [39129393, 9.09]),
   ('negative', [3132394, 0.73])],
  'source_id': 2,
  'total': 430395000}]
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you a lot, and thanks for using the lambda  ! i guess i had to dig deeper :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a list. So you can sort the list that contains your dictionaries using one value or more that are contained in the dictionary itself as key, but you cannot sort a dictionary. Dictionaries don't work like that.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = [{'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
                        'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
                        'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
         'source_id': 2,
         'total': 430395000},
        {'percentage': {'negative': [3132394, 0.73],
                        'neutral': [388133213, 90.18],
                        'positive': [39129393, 9.09]},
         'source_id': 2,
         'total': 430395000}]


def get_positive_pct(entry):
    # sort by the seconds element in the positive list - you can change it once your post is stable..
    return entry['percentage']['positive'][1]


sorted_data = sorted(data, key=get_positive_pct)
```